# Trying to create a Swift Realm Data Model

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have looked at the Realm.io docs. I am working on an application to track my vehicle expenses. I have put together what I think might work for a data model in Realm, but I am new to it and not sure if this is something that will work or if there is a better way to do it. Here is what I have, and I have not put this in a project and tried to compile yet. The realm.io docs are a little vague to me, so maybe someone can tell me what you think. I have included some comments in places that I am just not sure how to achieve what I'm going for...

```
    // Vehicle model
class Vehicle : RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = “”
    dynamic var number = “”
    dynamic var currentMiles = 0
    dynamic var entries = RLMArray(objectClassName: Entry.className())
}

// Entry model
class Entry: RLMObject {
    dynamic var vehicle: Vehicle //??
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var expense = 0.0
    dynamic var mileage : Vehicle.currentMiles // want to update the Vehicle mileage with each entry

}

// Gas model
class Gas: Entry {
    dynamic var gallons = 0
    dynamic var pricePerGallon = 0.0
}

// OilChange model
class OilChange : Entry {
    dynamic var milesBetweenChanges = 0
}

// Other Service model
class OtherService: Entry {
    dynamic var notes = “”
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track! The only model that needs work is `Entry`, I think. First, here's your model with my annotations:

```
// Entry model
class Entry: RLMObject {
    dynamic var vehicle: Vehicle // This is valid Swift, but you'll need to set the value in the designated initializer (`init()`).
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var expense = 0.0
    dynamic var mileage : Vehicle.currentMiles // This isn't valid Swift, since `Vehicle` is a class, and doesn't have a `currentMiles` member
}
```

What you want is something like this:

```
// Entry model
class Entry: RLMObject {
    dynamic var vehicle = Vehicle() // Use a default value so that `init()` succeeds, but you can still use `init(vehicle: Vehicle)` in your code
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var expense = 0.0
    dynamic var mileage = 0

    init() {
        // Must override init() when adding a convenience initializer
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(vehicle: Vehicle) {
        super.init()
        self.vehicle = vehicle
        mileage = vehicle.currentMiles
    }
}
```

It's unfortunate that you find Realm's docs vague. Please let us know if there's anything in particular you'd like us to clarify. We're a pretty approachable bunch!

Comment: I am designing an app and have decided to use Realm. I apologize for saying your documentation is vague. It just wasn't clicking with me, or actually it was and I just didn't realize it. The convenience initializer is something I didn't think to do.

I think it just feels like it should be harder to use. I look at it and say to myself, "nope - you left something out somewhere, that should have took longer". 

Your documentation is not vague, it is just me being insecure or something. Is this the best place to ask questions? I appreciate your response and your framework. Awesome stuff.

Comment: You can continue to ask questions here (make sure to use the "realm" tag). Good luck!